# How do I configure namecheap for "arbitrarily-nested" wildcard subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, namecheap

I'm trying to set up something like nyud.net, where any arbitrary chain of subdomains resolves to the same CNAME record (which in my case points to an amazon elastic load balancer). Ex: www.gogle.com.nyud.net:8080 points to one of their cache servers, which looks at the HOST header and returns www.google.com.

I'm using namecheap as my dns host. Adding a CNAME record for *.mydomain.com doesn't seem to do anything (nslookup gives NXDOMAIN for all subdomains).

What do I have to do to set this up? Do I have to use something fancier than namecheap (like route53)?

Answer (score 7):

Solved my own problem. This works if you create a CNAME record with * as the subdomain; I was putting *.mydomain.com (which is wrong).

Comment: Just had to say thanks for this. I have been trying to get this to work on namecheap for a while now.

Comment: If someone needs to add a sub-subdomain to namecheap - like `foo.subdomain.yourdomain.io` or `bar.subdomain.yourdomain.io` - it's just the same, you only need to add `*.subdomain` into Namecheaps `Host` field. Now every subsubdomain should work.